# Do we have to hardcode for localization in angular-translate for every language?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, localization, internationalization, angular-translate

Here i am doing the translation for 2 languages 'en' and 'de'

```
 app.config(['$translateProvider', function($translateProvider) {
  $translateProvider.translations('en', {
   'name': 'Hello',
   'FOO': 'This is a paragraph'
  });
 $translateProvider.translations('de', {
  'name': 'Hallo',
  'FOO': 'Dies ist ein Absatz'
  });
 $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('de');
}])
```

I am hardcoding the value for the key. How can we change the hello to hallo without hardcoding if we choose 'de' language?

Comment: "Hardcoding" as opposed to what exactly?

Comment: If i have a string "hello" in browser and if i change the language to "de" , the browser should display "hallo" and i dont want to hardcode it in my code.

Comment: Uhm, yes...!? That's exactly what angular-translate does...!? You seem to be somewhat confused about the basics of how to use it, so supply more information about what you're trying exactly.

Comment: for eg: if i want "Do we have to hardcode for localization in angular-translate for every language?"  to be converted to "de" language. How can i do it using anguarjs?

Comment: Are you asking whether you can just write `<span translate>Hello</span>`, and it will automagically be translated to "Hallo", without you writing a `$translateProvider.translations('de', { .. })` anywhere?!

Comment: yes.. is there any way to do this..we just specify the language and it changes it according to that language

Comment: No. You're asking for machine translation, which is a) very bad quality compared to manual translation, and b) not what angular-translate does.

Comment: No idea about Angular but some translation toolsets provide tools to scan source code and generate or update the language files and some template engines provide syntantic sugar to make the text insertion less verbose. But you always need to clearly identify translateble strings—the computer won't figure out what your text mean.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your translations into a separate file and load it as JSON. This way your localisation is not in your code.
As an example you can configure it:

```
$translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({prefix: 'l10n/', suffix: '.json'});
```

Which will try to load `l10n/de.json` for `de` language from your server. Just make sure to include `angular-translate-loader-static-files` dependency.